# Memory leak with three.js and many shapes

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, three.js

I have created some code which very quickly eats up memory and dies.

I have whittled this down to the torus generation / removal sections of the code. I have checked that the length of the scene array and my torus array are shrunk as shapes are removed so they appear to be well managed, but I am not sure where the memory is leaking.

Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/eVwP3/

Comment: What browser are you using? I ran the animation for several minutes on Chrome and didn't notice any increase in memory once the animation got going.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox, but apparently having it in jsfiddle seems to help! The actual reason for my problem was not deallocating the objects, as WestLangley notes below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `webGLRenderer`, after removing a mesh with

```
scene.remove( mesh );
```

you can deallocate the memory with

```
mesh.dispose();
geometry.dispose();
material.dispose();
texture.dispose();
```

See http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_test_memory.html and http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_test_memory2.html.

EDIT: updated to three.js r.69

P.S. Nice demo. You might want to consider creating a pool of objects and reusing them, rather than continually allocating and deallocating.

Comment: Since r52 you also need to do `mesh.deallocate()` `geometry.deallocate()`, `material.deallocate()` and `texture.deallocate()`. With ES6's WeakMap these won't be needed.

Comment: Also, this example should serve as good reference: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_test_memory.html

Comment: But yes, I would use a pool of objects (an array) and reuse them instead of constantly creating and removing objects.

Comment: deallocating everything worked, but I have now adjusted it to use a pool. One thing - I was creating a torus with a segment complexity depending on its initial size, but I haven't been able to work out how to adjust the segments of an already existing torus - can it be done?

http://jsfiddle.net/eVwP3/1/

Comment: You really need to accept this answer and post a new issue at this point, but the answer to your torus question is 'no'.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a question asking n00b, be gentle :-D

Comment: For this pool system to work, I simply make an array of all meshes I'm going to use, preload them and then when I need them simply add them to the scene? So no need anymore to deallocate objects?