# three.js memory leak .dispose() not working / wrong usage

Tags: javascript, d3.js, memory-leaks, three.js

Good day!

Have issue with memory handling. I read lots of forums but still can't find whats wrong with my code.

I'm working on project where I combine d3.js with three.js to visualize nodes like planets on orbits in space.
I have a lot of data - like 8K planets in 8+ orbits. But when I try to load new data - I can't destroy current tree without memory leak.

I would be grateful for any help! Here is part of code where I create planets and where I try to destroy them:

```
function initTree(root) {
    var start, end;

    var nodes = tree.nodes(root); //this is d3.js tree init
    var depth = getDepth(root);

    var first_x_offset = nodes[0].x;
    if (isNaN(first_x_offset)) {first_x_offset = 0}

    //create orbits
    var orbitTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/orbit_texture.png');
    var orbitMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: orbitTexture, transparent:true, side: THREE.DoubleSide, alphaTest: 0.05, opacity:0.3});
    var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 6, 6);

    var orbitSize = 30;
    for (var k=1; k<depth; k++) {
        var orbit = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CircleGeometry(orbitSize*k, 64), orbitMaterial);
        orbit.rotation.x = -90*Math.PI/180;
        orbit.name = 'orbit';
        scene.add(orbit);
    }
    //end orbits

    //camera position
    camera.position.x = 0;
    camera.position.y = 70;
    camera.position.z = -orbitSize*depth-100;

    controls.target.x = 0;
    controls.target.y = 0;
    controls.target.z = 0;

    camera.up.x = 0;
    camera.up.y = 1;
    camera.up.z = 0;

    //this is parent object to place in center
    var parent = new THREE.Object3D();
    parent.name = 'parent';
    scene.add(parent);

    y=0;

    spheres = {};
    objects = [];

    nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        if (d.type == 'BLANK') {return}
        d.x = d.x - first_x_offset;
        if (isNaN(d.x)) {d.x = 0}

        var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xdddddd, wireframe: false, opacity: 0.7, transparent: true});
        var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial );
        sphere.material.color.setHex(color_type[d.type]);

        sphere.castShadow = false; //maybe change to true
        sphere.id2 = y;
        d.id2 = y;
        sphere.d = d;

        sphere.scale.x = radius_type[d.type];
        sphere.scale.y = radius_type[d.type];
        sphere.scale.z = radius_type[d.type];

        sphere.name = 'sphere';

        spheres[y] = sphere;
        //count items of each type
        count_type[d.type]++;
        //how many nodes in tree
        y++;

        //create pivot
        var pivot = new THREE.Object3D;
        //rotate it
        pivot.rotation.y = d.x*Math.PI/180-90;
        //append to parent
        pivot.name = 'pivot';
        parent.add(pivot);
        //add mesh to pivot
        var default_distance = size/(depth-1);
            if (d.y > 0) {
                d.y = (Math.round(d.y/default_distance)) * (orbitSize-8.8);
            }

        sphere.position.x = d.y;
        sphere.position.y = 0; //should be 0!
        sphere.position.z = d.y;

        objects.push(sphere);

        pivot.add(sphere);
    });
    nodesLength = y;

    render();

    $('.loading').fadeOut(500);
    if (!animationId) {
        animate();
    }
    temp = null;
    nodes = null;

}
```

So I'm adding spheres to parent Object3D and then add it to scene.

And here is destroy function:

```
function destroyTree() {
    //spheres
    //console.log(renderer.info);
    var to_delete = [];

    for (var i=0; i<spheres.length; i++) {
        scene.remove(spheres[i]);
        spheres[i].material.dispose();
        spheres[i].geometry.dispose();
    }
    for (var i=0; i<spheres.length; i++) {
        spheres[i] = undefined;
    }
    spheres = {};
    for (var i=0; i<objects.length; i++) {
        scene.remove(objects[i]);
    }
    for (var i=0; i<objects.length; i++) {
        objects[i] = undefined;
    }
    objects = [];

    var parent = scene.getObjectByName('parent');
    scene.remove(parent);

    if (links.length) {
        for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
            scene.remove(links[i]);
        }
    }
    links = [];

    scene.traverse(function (child) {
        if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
            if (child.name.length) {
                to_delete.push(child);
            }
        }

    });

    for (var i=0; i<to_delete.length; i++) {
        scene.remove(to_delete[i]);

            to_delete[i].geometry.dispose();
            to_delete[i].material.dispose();
        to_delete[i] = undefined;
    }

    to_delete = [];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't traversing the scene find the spheres too?  And in that loop you could dispose directly without need for the to_delete array. If all speres are not children of the scene then maybe reconsider when to create them? These would just be optimizations and probably do little other then clarify where it might be leaking.

Then again maybe try holding an array of textures and releasing those directly?

Wait here it is, this link says to remove the objects and textures from the renderer as well.

[Memory leak in Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997669/memory-leak-in-three-js)

renderer.deallocateObject 
renderer.deallocateTexture

Comment: Thank you for your post.
renderer.deallocateObject( mesh );  is not supported anymore.

I figured out that issue is that I place spheres in object3D. Three.js has problems with freeing memory because of that as I can see.