# Memory is not getting released in Three.js

Tags: ios, react-native, three.js

*I am working on react-native project and i have to load 3JS Model On iOS Devices.*

*So what i did i am using webview of react-native and inside it i am loading my 3JS Model.*

***Now the problem is when i move to other screen of app the memory is still retained.***

*To resolve this issue i thought of disposing three.js objects(reference : [Memory leak in Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997669/memory-leak-in-three-js))*

`scene = new THREE.Scene(); //This is my scene`

`camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(2.5, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000); //This is my camera`

`renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();`

```
function dispose() {
  scene.remove(car);
  scene = null;
  camera = null;
  renderer.dispose();
}
```

Trying to remove react-native webview is also not releasing the memory.

```
this.setState({showWebview: false}, function(){

})
```

*How to resolve this issue?*

Comment: You should call `.dispose()` on materials, geometries and textures if you don't need them anymore.

Comment: Thanks@Mugen87 i will try that. But i am removing entire children of scene won't that enough?. should i dispose before removing it?

Comment: Yes, removing the 3D objects from the scene does not dispose the geometries, materials or textures. The renderer can't know if you want to reuse these entities at a later point in your app. So it's your task to free this stuff.

Comment: Thanks again. I was busy with some other stuff and it's late night here 12.53 AM. i will try tomorrow.

Comment: Is the webview being used after the page change? It seems like the easiest most effective way to free up that memory is to close the webview entirely when not needed.

Comment: yes it's web-view that we are loading and it's free up memory when we close the webview. But the model itself takes 500 mb of ram is there any other way of achieving it instead of using 3JS.