# load obj and mtl file by three.js OBJMTLLoader.js causes memory leak after multi-times load

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, three.js

I get a memory leak when load several obj mesh with mtl file by three.js, here is my step:

First, open this page: http://idazhenhan.github.io/threejs/loader/index.html, after <del>data loaded</del> click 'load', you will see some yellow meshes on screen when you move your mouse slightly;

Then, if you use windows, just open you task manager,  see how much memory the browser tab cost, record it.

Last, <del>click 'reload'</del> re-click 'load' <del>or 'clear'</del> on top-left of the page, watch the memory cost in task manager again, you will see, the memory is growing up and/or seemed will never free.

I write some release code at the end of the index.js, here it is:

```
function reload() {
    var indexes = [];
    for (var index in scene.children) {
        if(scene.children[index].name.indexOf('test') !== -1){
            indexes.push(scene.children[index]);
        }
    }
    for(var index in indexes){
        scene.remove(indexes[index]);
    }
    load();
};
```

I have change the two main functions:

```
function load() {
    clear();
    var paths = [];
    for(var i=1;i<=4;i++){
        paths.push({obj: i + '/model_1v.obj', mtl: i + '/model_1v.mtl'});
    }

    var onProgress = function(xhr) {
        if (xhr.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
        }
    };

    var onError = function(xhr) {};

    THREE.Loader.Handlers.add(/\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader());
    for(var i=0;i<paths.length;i++){
        var path = paths[i];
        var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
        loader.load(path.obj, path.mtl, function(model) {
            model.name='test-' + i;
            scene.add(model);
        }, onProgress, onError);
    }
}

function clear() {
    THREE.Cache.clear();
    var models = [];
    for (var i in scene.children) {
        if(scene.children[i].name.indexOf('test') !== -1){
            models.push(scene.children[i]);
        }
    }
    for(var i in models){
        scene.remove(models[i]);
        models[i].traverse(
           function(obj){
                if (obj instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                    obj.geometry.dispose();
                    obj.material.dispose();
                }
            }, true
        );
    }
    models.length = 0;
};
```

But it is still invalid, if you are interested of this, you can clone the code at here : https://github.com/idazhenhan/idazhenhan.github.io.git , then run the code on you local server, you will see the problem clearly.

Is there any one can help me to solve it?

Comment: Geometry has a dispose() method.

Comment: I have change the main function above, but it's still invalid.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945092/memory-leak-with-three-js-and-many-shapes?rq=1

Comment: yes, i read the answer several days ago, and i tried the method, now i find there is a global cache in Three.js, THREE.Cache, i find some cache data in it's 'files' property, so, before execute load(), i invoke THREE.Cache.clear(), the new code is upload, i saw the problem still   is here :(

Comment: are you still using the reload() function? because the link on top still uses reload().

Comment: ah, sorry, the github.io page is not update just now for my email is not verified... now the github pages code is updated, try again

Comment: it seems the pages is not updated correctly, please clone the .git to local to test

Comment: the pages is updated, if you are still interested on it, you can try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the javascript garbage collector (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) to kick in all references to an object must be zero. One way to tell javascript that you are done with an object is to set it to `undefined`. In addition you need to `dispose()` all of the group of objects underneath. Here is my version of disposing a hierarchy.

After your call to `scene.remove(models[i]);`

Use it: `disposeHierarchy (object, disposeNode);` or `disposeNode (node);`

```
var debugging = false;
var indent = "", indent_level = 0;

function disposeNode (node)
{
    if (debugging) console.log (indent_level + " " + indent + "\"" + node.name + "\"");

         if (node instanceof THREE.Camera)
    {
        if (debugging) console.log (indent + "\"" + node.name + "\"" + " " + "\"" + node.type + "\"" + " Camera");

        node = undefined;
    }
    else if (node instanceof THREE.Light)
    {
        if (debugging) console.log (indent + "\"" + node.name + "\"" + " " + "\"" + node.type + "\"" + " Light");

        node.dispose ();
        node = undefined;
    }
    else if (node instanceof THREE.Mesh)
    {
        if (debugging) console.log (indent + "\"" + node.name + "\"" + " " + "\"" + node.type + "\"" + " Mesh");

        if (node.geometry)
        {
            if (debugging) console.log (indent + indent + "I have Geometry");

            node.geometry.dispose ();
            node.geometry = undefined;
        }

        if (node.material)
        {
            if (node.material instanceof THREE.MeshFaceMaterial)
            {
                if (debugging) console.log (indent + indent + "I have many Materials");

                $.each (node.material.materials, function (idx, mtrl)
                {
                    if (mtrl.map)           mtrl.map.dispose ();
                    if (mtrl.lightMap)      mtrl.lightMap.dispose ();
                    if (mtrl.bumpMap)       mtrl.bumpMap.dispose ();
                    if (mtrl.normalMap)     mtrl.normalMap.dispose ();
                    if (mtrl.specularMap)   mtrl.specularMap.dispose ();
                    if (mtrl.envMap)        mtrl.envMap.dispose ();

                    mtrl.dispose ();    // disposes any programs associated with the material
                    mtrl = undefined;
                });
            }
            else
            {
                if (debugging) console.log (indent + indent + "I have Material");

                if (node.material.map)          node.material.map.dispose ();
                if (node.material.lightMap)     node.material.lightMap.dispose ();
                if (node.material.bumpMap)      node.material.bumpMap.dispose ();
                if (node.material.normalMap)    node.material.normalMap.dispose ();
                if (node.material.specularMap)  node.material.specularMap.dispose ();
                if (node.material.envMap)       node.material.envMap.dispose ();

                node.material.dispose ();   // disposes any programs associated with the material
                node.material = undefined;
            }
        }

        node = undefined;
    }
    else if (node instanceof THREE.Object3D)
    {
        if (debugging) console.log (indent + "\"" + node.name + "\"" + " " + "\"" + node.type + "\"" + " Object3D");

        node = undefined;
    }
    else
    {
        if (debugging) console.log (indent + "UNKNOWN " + "\"" + node.name + "\"" + " " + "\"" + typeof node + "\"");
    }
}

function disposeHierarchy (node, callback)
{
    indent += "    ";
    indent_level++;

    for (var i = node.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        var child = node.children[i];
        disposeHierarchy (child, callback);
        callback (child);
    }

    indent = indent.substr (4); // remove 4 spaces from indent
    indent_level--;
}
```

Comment: GREAT !  The memory usage is reduced a lot, thank you very much!