# We render a 3d model on the web by using web-ifc-viewer package in react js code

Tags: reactjs, three.js, webassembly, ifc

I am displaying the 3d model through web-ifc-viewer methods (Ifc Viewer API),
But when I use this and every time I load a 3d model it takes a certain amount of memory space.
When changing another 3D model I need to clear the previous memory space, for that I used the web-ifc-viewer methods dispose,
`viewer[1].dispose(); material.dispose(); geometry.dispose();`

what else do I need to do

i tried them with these reference
https://github.com/IFCjs/web-ifc-viewer/issues/147
[Memory leak with three.js and many shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945092/memory-leak-with-three-js-and-many-shapes)